# How to convert Graphics3D object into an Image3D object?

Tags: graphics3d, conversion, image3d

How does one convert a `Graphics3D` object into an `Image3D` object? E.g., start with `Plot3D[x^2 - y^2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]`.

Comment: Are you interested only in conversion, or creation too?

Comment: @Kuba: primarily conversion. (The ref/Image3D page shows how to generate some `Image3D` objects from some 4D arrays of reals, and of course using `Import` with a data object that is already `"Image3D"`)

Comment: @Kuba, my question is how to obtain an `Image3D` object if you already have a `Graphics3D` object -- not how you obtain an `Image3D` object by starting with a function of 3 variables and picking points as in your example with `UnitStep`.

Comment: Ok, just wasn't sure. :)

Answer (score 17):

If you already have a `Graphics3D` object, then you can recreate an `Image3D` object by stacking slices of your graphics along an axis. Here's an example. We start with your object:

```
obj = Plot3D[x^2 - y^2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Using the following rudimentary "slice" function, we can generate slices of the function at a given value of $x$:

```
slice[obj_, x_, dx_] := Show[obj, ViewPoint -> {∞, 0, 0}, 
    PlotRange -> {{x, x + dx}, All, All}, Axes -> False, Boxed -> False]

slice[obj, 0, 0.01]
```

[image]

Now generate such slices for all $x$, rasterize and grab the `ImageData` and stack the frames:

```
frames = Table[ImageData@Thinning@ColorNegate@ColorConvert[#, "Grayscale"] &@
    Rasterize@slice[obj, x, 0.05], {x, -1, 1, 0.01}];

Image3D[frames]
```

[image]

As you can see, the reconstruction is not perfect, and this arises from having to artificially sample the `Graphics3D` object by manipulating the plot ranges. Depending on how quickly the function changes within the chosen `dx`, the reconstruction could get worse/better. Note that you also need to choose the sampling such that the aspect ratio is maintained (I have only eyeballed it).

A much better reconstruction can be obtained either by generating frames using `Plot` (you probably can't avoid the Moiré patterns):

```
frames2 = 
  Table[ImageData@Thinning@ColorNegate@ColorConvert[#, "Grayscale"] &@
    Rasterize@
     Plot[x^2 - y^2, {x, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> {-1.5, 1.5}, 
      Axes -> False, Frame -> False], {y, -1, 1, 0.01}];

Image3D[frames2]
```

[image]

or by directly obtaining the samples as Kuba showed.

Comment: that's a start. I'll hold off accepting this in the hope of finding a solution that provides a much more faithful rendering of the `Grahics3D` object.

Comment: @murray Certainly. Could you perhaps explain why you want to convert to an `Image3D`? I'm not seeing any advantages to it over `Graphics3D`, but maybe I'm just being thick...

Comment: @R.M. Because we can use `Manipulate` to inspect a 3D object slice by slice?

Comment: @matheorem, and `ClipPlanes` is insufficient for your needs? Honestly, going from vector to raster is quite the step *down* here.

Comment: In 11.3, `Image3D[frames1]` is just giving me a fuzzy gray blur of a parallelepiped, with no hint of the saddle surface. And `Image3D[frames1]` is *not* starting with the given `Graphics3D` object.

Answer (score 9):

You could create a region using `DiscretizeGraphics` and find points within a certain distance of the surface using `RegionDistance`

```
g = Normal @ Plot3D[x^2 - y^2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}];

f = RegionDistance @ DiscretizeGraphics @ g;

data = Array[f[{##}] &, {60, 60, 60}, {-1.1, 1.1}];

Image3D[Clip[data, {0.05, 0.05}, {1, 0}]]
```

[image]

Comment: The expression `DiscretizeGraphics@g` generates error message for me: "DiscretizeGraphics: The function DiscretizeGraphics is not implemented for Directive[Specularity...."

Comment: In version 11,we should drop that `Normal` and the surface have a thickness?

Comment: In 11.3 (whether with or without the `Normal`, the resulting `Image3D` completely changes the oriientation of the saddle surface.

Answer (score 5):

Here's something more fun than practical.

We can simulate an MRI / CT scanner by reconstructing from projected images.

```
g = AnatomyPlot3D[Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "LeftFemur"], PlotTheme -> "XRay"]
```

[image]

Note that it's important to have some sort of transparency in the objects being 'scanned'. This will better simulate an x-ray.

Normally a CT will only perform a half rotation, but here we will combine 2 CTs by taking a full rotation. This will give a higher quality result. Here are the simulated x-rays:

```
projectGraphic[g_, α_] := Show[g, ViewPoint -> {Cos[α], Sin[α], 0}, 
  ViewProjection -> "Orthographic", SphericalRegion -> True, ViewAngle -> 1.6]

fcnt = 64;
rsz = 180;

projections = Monitor[
  Table[
    Rasterize[projectGraphic[g, α], RasterSize -> rsz, ColorSpace -> "Grayscale"], 
    {α, 0, 2π - π/fcnt, π/fcnt}
  ], 
  ProgressIndicator[α, {0, 2π}]
];

ListAnimate[projections]
```

[image]

Now we can create the slices:

```
radons1 = Image3DSlices[ImageRotate[Image3D[projections[[1 ;; fcnt]]], {π/2, {0, -1, 0}}], All, 2];
slices1 = InverseRadon /@ radons1;

radons2 = Image3DSlices[ImageRotate[Image3D[projections[[fcnt+1 ;; -1]]], {π/2, {0, -1, 0}}], All, 2];
slices2 = InverseRadon /@ radons2;
```

Reconstruct the orignal object by combining both CT scans:

```
recon = ImageAdjust @ ImageMultiply[
  Image3D[slices1], 
  ImageRotate[Image3D[slices2], π]
];

Image3D[RidgeFilter[recon], BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1.7}] // ImageAdjust
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As of version 11.2 there's [`RegionImage`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionImage.html).

```
g = Plot3D[x^2 - y^2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}];

RegionImage[DiscretizeGraphics[g]]
```

[image]

Comment: This works - "sort of ": it is *very* slow, and the result, which does have head `Image3D` has an unwanted Moire-like pattern on the surface and an unwanted light-gray parallelepiped-shaped blob filling the box.

Comment: @murray, "an unwanted light-gray parallelepiped-shaped blob filling the box" - at least for that part, you just need to change the `ColorFunction` setting: `Image3D[RegionImage[DiscretizeGraphics[g]], ColorFunction -> "WhiteBlackOpacity"]`

Comment: @murray The Moire-like pattern comes from antialiasing. `RegionImage` returns a grayscale image where a voxel value indicates how much of the region intersects with it. In addition to `ColorFunction`, changing volume lighting can help hide this effect: `Image3D[RegionImage[DiscretizeGraphics[g]], Method -> {"VolumeLighting" -> "EnhancedEdge", "InterpolateValues" -> True}]`.

Comment: And FWIW specifying a thicker surface with `RegionImage[DiscretizeGraphics[g], Method -> {"Thickness" -> 3}]` seems to speed things up.