# Is there a substitute for the "Show" function to use within the Mathematica kernel?

Tags: graphics3d, conversion, image3d

I needed to implement a function to convert an object from Graphics3D to Image3D, basically a 3D version of rasterisation (I need the geometry in a discretised form). I used the method suggested by R.M. in this post:[How to convert Graphics3D object into an Image3D object?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33274/how-to-convert-graphics3d-object-into-an-image3d-object), and it's working as I wanted. 
However, I need to run my code within a kernel from a terminal, and the Show function being used in "slice" requires the frontend. Is there a way of substituting the Show function with something else that can be executed easily within the kernel?

Comment: Look up `UsingFrontEnd`.

Comment: @ilian, thank you! That looks promising :)