# 3D input in EdgeDetect giving 2D output

Tags: graphics3d

I am trying to use the EdgeDetect function to determine the edges in my 3D figure. I have successfully done this with 3D figures created by an Image3D function. I now have a figure created by Graphics3D, however when I input this into the EdgeDetect function I get a 2D image as the output. What would allow me to get a 3D output?

```
x = Graphics3D[
GraphicsGroup[{Opacity[0.3], Cylinder[{{3, 3, 0}, {3, 3, 7}}, 10], 
Sphere[{1, 2, 1}, 1], Sphere[{7, 2, 1}, 1], Sphere[{7, 5, 3}, 1], 
Sphere[{4, 7, 3}, 1], Sphere[{5, 2, 1}, 1], Sphere[{3, 5, 6}, 1], 
Sphere[{3, 8, 6}, 1], Sphere[{7, 2, 7}, 1]}], Boxed -> False]

z = EdgeDetect[x]
```

Comment: To use `EdgeDetect` you need an `Image3D`. This question, [33274](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33274/how-to-convert-graphics3d-object-into-an-image3d-object), might help converting your graphics.