# How to get the image data of AnatomyPlot3D?

Tags: graphics3d, curated-data, entity, 3d-printing, anatomy

If I have a 3D plot, I can get its image data by using `ImageData` as below:-

```
Plot1 = Import["ExampleData/CTengine.tiff", "Image3D"];
PlotData1 = ImageData@Plot1;
PlotReconstructed1=Image3D@PlotData1
```

[image]

As you can see, the 3D image of the cheese `Plot_Reconstructed1` is reconstructed at the last line. However, if I do same for Anatomy image:-

```
Plot2 = AnatomyPlot3D[Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "LeftFemur"]];
PlotData2 = ImageData@Plot2;
PlotReconstructed2=Image3D@PlotData2
```

[image]

`Plot_Reconstructed2` is a flattened bone, which is not what I want. I want it to be same as `plot2`. The problem is, when I am trying to extract the image data by using `ImageData@Plot2`, the data `PlotData2` extracted was wrong (i.e. 3 pixe in width only).

How can I fix the error? Many thanks!

Comment: Your problem is that the result of `AnatomyPlot3D[]` is `Graphics3D[]` and not the desired `Image3D[]`. To do that conversion, see [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33274).

Comment: Also, don't use `_` in your variable names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the dimensions of `PlotData2`:

```
PlotData2 // Dimensions
```

> ```
> {432, 110, 4}
> ```

It represents a 4 channel 2D image. What's happening here is the syntax of `ImageData` is a bit forgiving. Normally it expects an `Image` or `Image3D` object, but when given a `Graphics` or `Graphics3D` object it will rasterize them to a 2D `Image` first.

Now when you pass `PlotData2` to `Image3D`, it see a nice 3-tensor of dimensions 432 x 110 x 4 and so it creates a 3D image of those dimensions. Effectively stacking the output of `ColorSeparate` on top of each other.

Your working example started out as a 3D image and so things just worked.

---

The only built in way to rasterize an object in 3D is [`RegionImage`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionImage.html), which needs a valid region as input. Luckily we can find such a region for anatomical data:

```
mr = Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "LeftFemur"]["MeshRegion"];

im = RegionImage[mr]
```

[image]

---

One caveat here is `reg` just represents the boundary surface of the femur and so your raster will be hollow:

```
{Area[mr], Volume[mr]}
```

> ```
> {61317.9, 0}
> ```

```
Image3DSlices[im, 100]
```

> [image]

If you'd like your raster to be solid, you could first convert your surface mesh into a solid through `BoundaryMeshRegion`:

```
imsolid = RegionImage[BoundaryMeshRegion[MeshCoordinates[mr], MeshCells[mr, 2]]];

Image3DSlices[imsolid, 100]
```

> [image]

Conversion to `BoundaryMeshRegion` might not work for every anatomical entity though -- not all have 'watertight' surface mesh representations.